# question about uniform continuity

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity, piecewise-continuity

I have a function $f:[a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f$ is piecewise continuous in the intervals $[a, t_1],$ $(t_1, t_2],$ $(t_2, t_3],$...., $(t_n, b].$ Can we say that $f$ is uniformly piecewise continuous on $[a, b]?$

Comment: Let $f$ be a function on a closed, bounded interval $[a, b]$. You might say $f$ is _uniformly piecewise continuous_ if the restriction of $f$ to each of the stated intervals is uniformly continuous, but that definition doesn't look useful, since it doesn't imply continuity of $f$, let alone uniform continuity. The usual reason to introduce terminology is to shorten the statements of theorems, proofs, and other definitions....

Answer (score 2):

No. A counter example is $f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ defined as

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0, &-1 \leq x \leq 0 \\ \frac 1x, &0<x\leq 1 \end{cases}$$

Comment: If a function $f$ has a finite value at each $t_k^+?$

Comment: Then you can replace $\frac 1x$ with $\sin \left( \frac 1x \right)$

Answer (score 2):

Even if the function is left/right continuous at each $\;t_k\;$ *but not continuous necessarily* at all of them you will lose unif. continuity:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x,&0\le x<1\\{}\\7,&1\le x\le2\end{cases}$$

Thus, for example, you can take

$$\begin{cases}\{x_n\}=\left\{\frac{n-1}n\right\}\subset[0,2]\\{}\\\{y_n\}=\{1\}\subset[0,2]\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies |y_n-x_n|=\frac1n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;,\;\;\text{yet}$$$${}$$

$$|f(y_n)-f(x_n)|=\left|7-\frac{n-1}n\right|=\frac{6n+1}n\rlap{\;\;\;\;/}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

and we're done.

Comment: But in this last example you are suppose to check the uniform continuity in the interval $[0, 1)$ but you are checking in $[0, 1]$

Comment: @VijayakumarMuni I don't understand what you mean: the function is defined piecewise in $\;[0,1)\,,\,[1,2]\;$, being piecewise continuous **and bounded** at each, and it is shown that it is *not* unif. continuous. Why do you think I "have* to check unif. cont. **only** in $\;[0,1)\;$ ? instead in the *whole domain* $\;[0,2]\;$ ??

Comment: Because i need the uniform continuity of f piecewise. But not on the entire domain

Comment: My question is whether f is uniform continuous on $[0, 1)?$ And also whether f is uniformly continuous on $[1, 2)?$

Comment: @VijayakumarMuni Well, that was **not** your original question, as you can read it in your own question, where you asked about unif. cont. in $\;[a,b]\;$ , not in each $\;[a,t_1),\,[t_1,t_2)\;$ , etc., and which is what I address in my answer. Anyway, my example is almowst trivially unif. cont. in each subinterval...

Comment: Dear friend, I asked whether f is  piecewise uniformly continuous function

Comment: @VijayakumarMuni Then your question is unclear...and not that interesting, imo. My example is u.c. in each subinterval, but the other answer's example isn't. It all depends on the functions given, yet in both examples you lose overall unif. cont.